# How can I justify this set manipulation to show a result in probability?

Tags: probability-theory

I am working on the following problem:

[image]

Proof: Let $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$ and $c < d$. We have \begin{align*}P(a < x \leq b, c < Y \leq d) &= P[\{a < x \leq b\}\cap\{c < Y \leq d\}]\\ &= P[(\{X \leq b\} \sim \{X \leq a\})\cap(\{Y \leq d\} \sim \{Y \leq c\})].\end{align*}

Now if there was some sort of "DeMorgan's-esque" distributive law for intersections and set differences, we'd arrive at the desired result: $$P(\{X \leq b\}\cap\{Y \leq d\}) - P(\{X \leq b\}\cap\{Y \leq c\}) - P(\{X \leq a\}\cap\{Y \leq d\}) + P(\{X \leq a\}\cap\{Y \leq c\}).$$

I don't know the justification for this though.

Comment: "The current answers do not contain enough detail." Nice to know.

Comment: I did up-vote your answer. But I also asked in the OP, if "there was some sort of 'DeMorgan's-esque' distributive law for intersections and set differences?" The answer provided does not explain this. I also explained in the comments that the book has never mentioned the pointwise identity or that notation, so it is likely not what the author intended, despite being correct.

Comment: Intersection is distributive over set difference: $$\begin{aligned}(A\cap B)\setminus(A\cap C)&=(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap C)'\\ &=(A\cap B)\cap(A'\cup C')\\ &=((A\cap B)\cap A')\cup((A\cap B)\cap C')\\ &=\emptyset\cup(A\cap(B\cap C'))\\ &=A\cap(B\setminus C).\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 6):

Integrate the pointwise identity $$\mathbf 1_{a < x \leq b,c < y \leq d}=(\mathbf 1_{x \leq b}-\mathbf 1_{x \leq a})\cdot(\mathbf 1_{y \leq d}-\mathbf 1_{y \leq c})=\mathbf 1_{x \leq b,y \leq d}-\mathbf 1_{x \leq b,y \leq c}-\mathbf 1_{x \leq a,y \leq d}+\mathbf 1_{x\leq a,y \leq c}$$ with respect to $P_{(X,Y)}(\mathrm dx\mathrm dy)$.

Comment: Did - I am not doubting that this is correct, but are you certain that this is what the textbook would have intended for me to do? My book has never mentioned the pointwise identity or used that notation, which is why I am not sure if that would be the author's intent.

Comment: You ask me if I am certain that a textbook I know nothing about asks to do and not to do? Sorry but I am no psychic hence I cannot say. What I can tell you however is that the approach I suggest in my answer, based on indicator functions, does save a lot of head-scratching.

Comment: No, I'm not expecting you to have knowledge of my textbook. I guess what I am trying to ask is, is there a way to proceed from the last line that I have? Because the book implies that you can show this result using just the definition and elementary set theory.

Answer (score 2):

You have the four events
$$
A := [X\le a], \;B:=[X\le b], \; C:=[Y\le c], \; D:=[Y \le d].
$$
Since $A$ implies $B$, $$P(\neg A \wedge B \wedge X)=P(B\wedge X)-P(A\wedge B\wedge X)= P(B\wedge X) - P(A \wedge X)$$ for any $X$.  (For arbitrary $A$ and $B$, only the first equality would be sound.)  Similarly, since $C$ implies $D$, $$P(\neg C \wedge D \wedge Y)=P(D\wedge Y)-P(C\wedge D\wedge Y)=P(D\wedge Y)-P(C\wedge Y)$$
for any $Y$.  Putting these together gives
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
P(a<X\le b, c<Y\le d) &=&
P(\neg A \wedge B \wedge \neg C \wedge D)\\&=&P(B\wedge \neg C\wedge D)-P(A \wedge \neg C \wedge D) \\
&=&\left(P(B\wedge D) - P(B\wedge C)\right)-\left(P(A\wedge D) - P(A\wedge C)\right) \\
&=&(F(b,d)-F(b,c))-(F(a,d)-F(a,c)) \\
&=&F(b,d)-F(b,c)-F(a,d)+F(a,c),
\end{eqnarray}
$$
which is what you wanted to show.